# how can i run async function from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio, aiogram

I am using aiogram to manage my telegram bot, the function of the bot is simple: it listens on a tcp connection port and posts the received string into my telegram group.
so far the bot on itself works perfectly and the socket server receives the data, but i can't seem to send what i received from socket into telegram group.

Here is the following code:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import asyncio
import threading
import socket
import queue


qu = queue.Queue()
MAIN_CHANNEL = "@**************"
bot = Bot(token="***************")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
prods = []


def handleClient(name, client):
    global prods
    request = None
    while request != 'quit':
        try:
            request = client.recv(1024).decode("utf8")
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("Done")
            break
        print(request)
        asyncio.create_task(postProduct(request))
        response = f"You [{name}] sent: {request}"
        try:
            client.send(response.encode())
        except BrokenPipeError:
            print(f"{name} disconnected.")
            break

    client.close()


def run_server():
    global qu
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(("localhost", 15437))
    server.listen(8)
    while True:
        name = "Client"
        client, _ = server.accept()
        qu.put(client)
        clientThread = threading.Thread(
            target=handleClient,
            name=name,
            args=(name, client))
        clientThread.start()


async def threadTask():
    mainServerThread = threading.Thread(
        target=run_server,
        name="MainServerThread"
    )
    mainServerThread.start()



async def postProduct(msg):
    await bot.send_message(MAIN_CHANNEL, msg)


async def on_startup(_):
    # await postProduct("test")
    asyncio.create_task(threadTask())


executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
```

in handleClient function i tried creating a task with asyncio and run the postProduct on it to post string into telegram group, but i got the following error when testing with netcat:
testing string

> Exception in thread Client:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> File "/home/belheart/Documents/amazon/TBot/main.py", line 25, in handleClient
> asyncio.create_task(postProduct(request))
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 336, in create_task
> loop = events.get_running_loop()
> RuntimeError: no running event loop
> /usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py:1018: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'postProduct' was never awaited
> self._invoke_excepthook(self)
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: You get an error because there is no asyncio environment in your secondary thread.  You don't have an event loop running so the task never executes.  Why are you creating a task at all?  Why not just call postProduct directly from handleClient and forget about asyncio?